# Commit masturbation in Ramadan

Tags: sin, ramadan, forgiveness, masturbation, helping

I always jena through my eyes,I mean watch those type videos and I done masturbation through my hands after that I leave it for 1 month maximum 4 months and Go to the prayers.After this I repeat it also repent and Ask forgiveness to Allah but now I commit masturbation in Ramadan I feel so guilty to my self My question is, I mean I broke my promise again and again will Allah forgive me? Please help me brother I can't understand anything I want to escape from it what can I do also will Allah forgive me if I repent again does it affected my life and my wishes by my sins please help me. What can I do.i feel like iam literally broken I am from India

Answer (score 1):

For your question 'will Allah forgive me?'  :

It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him) said:

I heard the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) say:

“A person committed a sin and said: ‘My Lord, I have sinned; forgive me.’

His Lord said: ‘Is My slave acknowledging that he has a Lord Who forgives sins and punishes for them? I have forgiven My slave.’
Then as much time passed as Allah willed, then he committed a sin and said, ‘My Lord, I have sinned; forgive me.’
His Lord said: ‘Is My slave acknowledging that he has a Lord Who forgives sins and punishes for them?  I have forgiven My slave.’

Then as much time passed as Allah willed, then he committed a sin and said, ‘My Lord, I have sinned; forgive me.’ His Lord said: ‘Is My slave acknowledging that he has a Lord Who forgives sins and punishes for them? I have forgiven My slave,’ – three times…”
[al-Bukhari, Muslim]
So even if you repeat the  sin  a hundred times or a thousand times or more, and you sincerely repent each time, your repentance will be accepted and your  sin will be erased.

Allah likes the sinner to seek His forgiveness and repent to Him, but the shaytan (devil) likes it when despair fills a person’s heart and prevents him from repenting and turning to Allah.

Also dear brother, don't loose hope in the mercy of Allah. The biggest mistake we could ever make after is to lose hope in Allah s.w.t’s Mercy.

Allah(SWT) says in the Quran:

قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ

Say, “O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful.”

(Surah Az-Zumar, 39:53)

He's telling the one who has sinned to not lose hope in his forgiveness in his mercy.

It was reported on the authority of Anas (may Allah be pleased with him), who said:
I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) say: Allah the Almighty said:

O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me, I shall forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind. O son of Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you. O son of Adam, were you to come to Me with sins nearly as great as the earth and were you then to face Me, ascribing no partner to Me, I would bring you forgiveness nearly as great as it.
[ related by at-Tirmidhi, also by Ahmad ibn Hanbal]

As for some ways to stop this habit, is  knowledge.  Knowing the seriousness of such actions .
Allāh, Glorified and Exalted is He, says in His Book:

{On the Day when their tongues, their hands, and their legs or feet will bear witness against them as to what they used to do.} [Sūrah An-Nūr 24:24]

{This Day, We shall seal up their mouths, and their hands will speak to Us, and their legs will bear witness to what they used to earn.} [Surah Yāsīn 36:65]

{Till, when they reach it (Hell-fire), their hearing (ears) and their eyes, and their skins will testify against them as to what they used to do. And they will say to their skins, "Why do you testify against us?" They will say: "Allah has caused us to speak, as He causes all things to speak, and He created you the first time, and to Him you are made to return."}
[Sūrah Fussilat 41:20-21]

Also ..Allah says in the quran:

{Mankind there has come to you a guidance from your Lord and a healing for (the diseases) in your hearts, and for those who believe a guidance and a mercy.}
(Yunus, 10:57)
So recite the Quran,  make some goals for yourself (for eg: reciting 6 pages every day after fair or memeorizing 6 ayahs every day)., or make monthly goals like memeorizing surah baqarah within two months,  or start with some smaller surahs.
For memeorizing I'd recommend you to YouTube asma huda recitation. Her students repeats after her and it's quite beautiful to listen to.

Get to know prophet Muhammd (saw)  , there's this series available in YouTube named 'meeting Muhammad-yaqeen institute', its just 10 minutes for each video,  best way to get to know our Rasool. Saw

Also try watching Muslim convert stories,  it increases iman.
Plus gain more knowledge about deen,  for Allah says :
“It is only those who have knowledge among His slaves that fear Allaah” [Faatir 35:28]
So Ask Allah to Grant you knowledge
{Rabbeee zidni ilma ; my Lord,  increase  me in knowledge} it's the best way to be safe from Shaytan's traps.

One of the easy way to Gain some little amount of knowledge is to   try listening to tafseers of surah from YouTube.(eg: surah Rahman by Nouman)  . There's alot other out there.

And remember this  famous quote which  says:
"Whoever has tasted the sweetness of iman will recognise the bitterness of sins"
So try to come closer to Allah and taste the sweetness of faith .
praying the 12 rawatib prayer is one way.
"Allaah will build a house in Heaven for whoever is diligent in observing 12 Sunnah Rak'aat (as follows): 4 Rak'aat before and 2 after the Dhuhr (Midday) Prayer, 2 after the Maghrib (Sunset Prayer), 2 after the Ishaa (Evening) Prayer and 2 before the Fajr (Dawn) Prayer." Hadith sahih narrated by at-Tirmidhi No. 379 and by others. Hadith No. 6183 in Sahih al-Jaami.

or start praying Witr or Dhuha prayer or the Tahajjud..

“Our Lord descends during the last third of each night to the lower heaven, and says: ‘Is there anyone whocalls on Me that I may respond to him? Is thereanyone who asks Me that I may give unto him? Is there anyone who requests My Forgiveness that I mayforgive him?’” (Bukhari and Muslim)

When you experience tahajjud, the late nightprayer, the rest of your life transforms. Suddenly, theburdens that once crushed you become light. The problemsthat were irresolvable become solved. And that closenessto your Creator, which was once unreachable, becomesyour only lifeline.

You should also try to learn Allah's 99 names and understand them.. For it will help you Know Allah better.
Lastly I'd recommend you to make  the morning nd evening adkhars for they are very beautiful and they can  protect you.
Here's a link to them :

https://islamqa.info/en/answers/217496/adhkaar-for-morning-and-evening

There is an app called tafheemul Quran and rakheehul makhtum or the sealed nectar in the playstore (free, in English also urdu),  you should try reading that to busy yourself with good things .

Hope it helps,
And May Allah bestow his Mercy care and protection on you Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

My brother listen Allah is most forgiving most merciful remember that always! I see you feel remorse run to Allah and promise him never to do it again. But you did commit a major sin but Allah can still forgive you with a sincere repentance you should stop this sin and when you feel like doing it remember who you are disobeying don’t look at the size of the sin look at who you are disobeying since you masturbated during Ramadan you have to make those days up. May Allah have mercy on you and remember Ramadan is the month of Allah’s mercy so do repent and stop this now because you never know when you will return to your lord.